# Why is creating a new project in AWS SDK for Java (Eclipse IDE) throwing a NoSuchMethodError?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, eclipse, maven, aws-sdk-java

I am getting started with the AWS SDK for Java in Eclipse IDE - have set it up using [this](https://aws.amazon.com/eclipse/) link.

Went to start programming and selected Create a New AWS Java Project (using one of the samples provided, in a new workspace), and pressed OK and it returned a NoSuchMethodError (copied & pasted below). Tried to make a new project without using a sample and still got the same error. What is going wrong?

```
void org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.IProjectConfigurationManager.createSimpleProject(org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject, org.eclipse.core.runtime.IPath, org.apache.maven.model.Model, java.lang.String[], org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.ProjectImportConfiguration, org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor)'
'void org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.IProjectConfigurationManager.createSimpleProject(org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject, org.eclipse.core.runtime.IPath, org.apache.maven.model.Model, java.lang.String[], org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.ProjectImportConfiguration, org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor)
```

Comment: *NoSuchMethodError* sonds like incompatible libraries

Comment: How would I check/fix incompatible libraries? @Jens

Comment: Library (jar) dependencies will depend on the type off program you build e.g the JSF API jars , RESTful services jars. Lookup the jars required for the type of program framework API, obtain them and add them to the project list in the GUI (libraries)before creating the project.

Comment: I think the problem is that the current Eclipse uses version 2 of the org.eclipse.m2e plug-ins which have changed a number of APIs - the AWS code appears to be trying to use the old version of the APIs and needs to be updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AWS Toolkit doesn't always support the latest Eclipse IDE versions. Try installing Eclipse 2021-12 version and install the AWS Toolkit there.

I had the same problem. Uninstalled Eclipse & installed 2021-12 and it worked for me.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to this thread: if you take a look at the repo for the AWS Eclipse plugin here: https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-eclipse you will see that there have not been any updates to this plugin for a 2 years, so I guess you may need to consider using another IDE for AWS Java development.

Perhaps consider a new IDE and/or a different programming language.  Neither are very low effort options =/